# How to run autoinstall on a specific user-data file depending on the host?

Tags: grub2, system-installation, uefi, pxe

The environment I'm working in has dozens of different servers, and several times per year new ones get added. We use PXE booting (Legacy/BIOS and EFI) for provisioning these new machines. I'm in the process of changing our network install process from the previous debian-installer mechanism to the new autoinstall / cloud-init mechanism.

A limitation that I've noticed is that the syslinux (BIOS) or grub.cfg entry (EFI) points to a specific `user-data` url, e.g. `http://example.org/ks/user-data`. But what if you have many different machines that you'd like provisioned? The `user-data` file mandates things like a `hostname` be set in the `identity` block, making these files only really suited to provision a single specific machine.

So, my first inclination was to generate a separate `user-data` file for each host, to serve up. But, since that URL is hard-coded in your syslinux/grub config, how is this possible?

tl;dr Is there some mechanism in the new autoinstall/cloud-init system that facilitates providing different configurations depending on the host that is being PXE booted?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches I have seen used.

1. Create a very basic `user-data` file that is used for all machines. Within that `user-data` file, use `early-commands` to create a machine specific configuration at `/autoinstall.yaml`.
2. Serve a custom `user-data` file to each device.  What you can do depends on the capabilities of your DHCP server and PXE image.  A simple solution is to serve different static files based on an attribute like MAC address.  A more complex solution could generate files dynamically.  Both Syslinux and Grub can change configuration based on MAC address, although I find Grub to be much more flexible.

**Other discussions**

These have more details and examples of the two approaches.

- [Fetch autoinstall based on MAC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290624/fetch-autoinstall-based-on-mac)
- [Choose autoinstall config by BIOS serial or mac](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1309505/choose-autoinstall-config-by-bios-serial-or-mac)
- [How do I automate network installation of many Ubuntu 18.04 systems with EFI and PXE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272400/how-do-i-automate-network-installation-of-many-ubuntu-18-04-systems-with-efi-and)